# Defining the halting problem for non-deterministic automata

Tags: turing-machines, automata, nondeterminism, halting-problem, linear-bounded-automata

The primary definition of Turing machine (TM), at least in my own reference
textbook (Hopcroft+Ullman 1979) is deterministic.

Hence my own understanding of the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is primarily for
deterministic TM, though I am aware that it may be considered for other kinds of automata.

I also noticed that determinism is often more or less implicit in the way
people often refer to TM or to the halting problem. [The wikipedia page
on the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is a good example of that.

But, there seem no reason for such a limitation. Given a family
$\mathcal F$ of automata that can be non-deterministic, the halting
problem for $\mathcal F$ may be defined as:

> Is there a uniform decision procedure such that, given an automaton $A\in\mathcal F$ and an input $x$, it can decide whether there is a
>     halting computation of $A$ on input $x$.

(This is not quite the same as saying that the computation of $A$ with input $x$ will terminate.)

Indeed, that seem the only way to give some sense to discussions about
the halting problem for [Linear Bounded Automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton) (LBA) which are
primarily non-deterministic automata.

So my question is whether I am correct, and whether there is a reason (and which reason)
for this apparently second class treatment of the halting problem for
non-deterministic automata.

Comment: If you think something is wrong in this question, would you be so kind as to  tell  what it is, so that we can all benefit from your knowledge and improve the post for all users. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

There are a few reasons I think we put less effort into  the Halting problem for non-deterministic models.

The first is that there are, in fact, two relevant halting problems for a ND model. Given an input $x$ and a non-deterministic machine $M$:

- Does there exist a valid run of $M$ on $x$ which halts?
- Does there exist a valid run of $M$ on $x$ which doesn't halt? i.e. do all valid runs halt?

For deterministic machines, these are identical, since there is exactly one valid run of $M$ on an input $x$. But for non-deterministic machines, there might be multiple runs. Which one you're interested in depends on your application.

Secondly, non-deterministic models are already unrealistic: they assume that you either have a magical box telling you which path to take, or that you have some form of infinite parallelism. Since non-deterministic and deterministic Turing Machines are equivalent in power, in most cases you just convert the machine into a determinstic one before you worry about halting.

As an extension of this, we don't care because proving something about a non-deterministic machine is at least as hard as proving something about an equivalent deterministic machine. We already know that there's no solution to the deterministic Halting Problem, so all it's really useful for is proving other problems undecidable through reductions. And it's always going to be less work to reduce to the deterministic halting problem, since it's easier than it's non-deterministic counterpart.

Comment: You state: "*But for non-deterministic machines, there might be
multiple runs. Which one you're interested in depends on your
application.*" Could you illustrate that statement with an example?
Then you state "*you just convert the machine into a deterministic one
before you worry about halting*". How is that done for a LBA?

Comment: LBA's are a subset of non-deterministic Turing Machines, so they can always be converted into deterministic Turing Machines using the usual method. I suspect there's special construction that can be used to convert to a machine with specific properties, so we can keep the extra reasoning ability we get from LBAs. I think it's going to look like a backtracking algorithm where linear space is used, except the call stack could potentially be exponentially large (I'm not sure, I'd have to look it up).

Comment: For multiple paths, consider two machines $M_1, M_2$, one which always halts on input $x$, and one which never does for $x$. We can make a new LBA $M$ which starts by non-deterministically choosing a boolean value. If it chooses true, it runs $M_1$ on input x. If it chooses false, it runs $M_2$ on $x$. Each choice of true and false is a different "run". Does this machine halt for $x$? There exists a path where it halts on $x$, but it does not halt for all paths reading $x$.

Comment: You suggest converting my non-deterministic LBA or TM into a
deterministic one if I am interested on halting issues.  And at the
same time you assert there are "*two relevant halting problems for a
ND model*". But there is only one relevant halting problem for
deterministic automata. So something must have been [lost in
translation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0335266). How do I reconcile facts?

Comment: The definition of acceptance follows the first definition of halting I put, so if you convert, that's the definition which is preserved. The DTM from an NTM will halt on any input where there exists an NTM path that halts. I'll try to update my answer soon.

Comment: For an LBA, converting to a DTM might not be the best option. What is your application? What specifically are you trying to do? That will probably help direct my answer, instead of me just trying to motivate why we do or don't care about it.

Comment: "And it's always going to be less work to reduce to the deterministic halting problem, since it's easier than it's non-deterministic counterpart." -- easier in which sense? I usually find reductions to harder problems easier.

Comment: As we know, every NTM can be transformed into an equivalent DTM by dovetailing. In one of the comments @jmite seems to suggest the same appraoch can be used for NLBA. However, as far as I know the problem whether NLBA and DLBA are equivalent still is open. The dovetailing construction simply may use more than linear additional space.

Comment: @HendrikJan It seems that halting of NLBA is rather addressed with [Savitch's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitch%27s_theorem). But it changes the linear bound into a quadratic one.

Comment: @HendrikJan sorry for the confusion, I meant that you could convert an NLBA into a DTM using the usual method.

Comment: @Raphael what I mean by this is that, to show problem $P$ undecidable, you show that you can use $P$ to simulate another undecidable problem. Since there's a trivial injective mapping from DTMs to NTMs, any reduction from NTM halting is also a reduction from DTM halting. Usually it would be less work to reduce from DTM halting, since it's a less difficult problem you're trying to simulate.

Comment: I just wrote an answer that discusses your suggestions. Your alternative to nondeterministic halting makes sense, but it is not narural because it lacks consistency with other definitions regarding nondeterministic automata.

Answer (score 6):

The halting problem is the quintessential $\Sigma_1$-complete problem, since it can be stated as:

> $H(P,x) \leftrightarrow \exists c \, \text{ s. t. $c$ is a halting computing of $P$ on $x$}$.

This suggests that your definition is a correct one. In general, every $\Sigma_1$-complete definition is "correct".

Comment: Unfortunately, I know close to nothing about arithmetical hierarchy.
Am I correct in understanding that $\Sigma_1$ represents
semi-decidable problems?  What about: $K(P,x)\leftrightarrow\forall c,
c\text{ is a computing of $P$ on $x\implies c$ is halting.}$. I am
asking because existential and universal quantifications seem to end
up in different classes, but it is all hazy for me. $K$ is also semi-decidable.

Comment: That is what I was afraid you would answer. I asked because I think
that I have a semi-decision procedure for it. So either my proof is
wrong, or I formalized my problem incorrectly. Basically it is jmite's
suggestion that non-deterministic halting on input $x$ could be defined by
requiring that all computations on $x$ halt. And I believed until now
I had a semi-decision for that.

Comment: Actually your definition isn't good for another reason: what do you mean by "$c$ is halting"? Either you mean that $c$, which is a-priori only an incomplete computation, is actually complete. In that case, $K(P,x)$ is never true, since you can take $c$ to be the empty computation. In any other case, it's not clear that the description of $c$ is finite, and it's also not clear that the predicate "$c$ is halting" is computable.

Comment: So in fact the problem is in $\Pi_1$ but probably not $\Pi_1$-complete.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for my naive reading. I thought the $c$ you used
stood for "complete" computations, which is apparently an error on the
domain quantified. I guess one can use only countable domains and the
set of non-halting computations of a nondeterministic TM does not
qualify. Also I guess the quantifiers tell us how bad the
computability may be, but offer no garantee that it is that bad. So it
seems that jmite's proposal is not easily expressed in a direct way in
the required "format", but my semi-decision procedure may be correct.

Answer (score 2):

you say there is an "apparent second class treatment" of the halting problem for nondeterministic machines. it does appear that nondeterminism was not considered historically until long after Turings creation of the deterministic TM & this may have something to do with research focus in the area. however the main point here is that the nondeterministic problem can easily be reduced to the deterministic problem, so one only needs to study the deterministic problem "without loss of generality".

furthermore, to counter the idea of "2nd class" here is at least one ref/ paper that studies the halting problem for nondeterministic machines and finds useful/ deep connections. some circumstantial evidence along the lines that CS research is so vast/ specialized, sometimes some starting research has been done in most areas, even seemingly narrow, and it can approach nearly meaningless or hairsplitting to rank different problems in their importance. and quite to the contrary, nondeterminism seems a very deep/ ubiquitous/ crosscutting concept in CS (key open questions like P vs NP are on it) & that aspect is likely to continue long into the future.

- [A Parameterized Halting Problem](http://basics.sjtu.edu.cn/~chen/papers/3hal-fel.pdf) / Chen, Flum

> Abstract. The parameterized problem p-Halt takes as input a nondeterministic
>   Turing machine M and a natural number n, the size of M
>   being the parameter. It asks whether every accepting run of M on empty
>   input tape takes more than n steps. This problem is in the class XPuni,
>   the class “uniform XP,” if there is an algorithm deciding it, which for
>   fixed machine M runs in time polynomial in n. It turns out that various
>   open problems of different areas of theoretical computer science are related
>   or even equivalent to p-Halt ∈ XPuni. Thus this statement forms a
>   bridge which allows to derive equivalences between statements of different
>   areas (proof theory, complexity theory, descriptive complexity, . . . )
>   which at first glance seem to be unrelated. As our presentation shows,
>   various of these equivalences may be obtained by the same method.

Answer (score 2):

### In a nutshell

There seems to be no good reason to neglect the halting problem in
settings that are not the classical one of deterministic Turing
machines, other than the fact that the classical halting problem
answers some major mathematical questions (such as the
[Entscheidungsproblem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem)), while variants are only interesting (?) technical
issues, but with less impact on the foundations.

After reviewing some of the arguments given in previous answers, I analyze and
compare the [two proposals by jmite](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44231/defining-the-halting-problem-for-non-deterministic-automata/44236#44236) for a possible definition of
"*nondeterministic*" halting in the case of nondeterministic
automata. The issue is not to define what halting means for a single
computation, but what it should mean for the set of possible
computations of a given nondeterministic automaton $A$ on a given
input $x$. This can then serve as a basis for defining the halting
problem on nondeterministic automata.

According to jmite's answer, this nondeterministic halting can be
defined as corresponding to the existence of at least one halting
computation (*existential halting*), or alternatively to requiring
that all possible computation be halting (*universal halting*). These
two definitions correspond to two different definitions of the
nondeterministic halting problem.

I show that, for Turing machines, the two definitions corresponds to
two distinct ways of determinizing the machine by dovetailing. From
this, I infer that the two variants of the nondeterministic halting
problem are both Turing equivalent to the classical deterministic
[halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

However, I also show that each of these definitions of halting is directly
related to a corresponding definition of the language recognized by a
Turing machine, and this relation can be simply expressed on the
condition of choosing consistent definitions.

Hence, given the usual definition of the language recognized by a
nondeterministic automaton, the natural definition of nondeterministic
halting is existential halting, as proposed in the original question.

Most of this analysis naturally extends to other types of automata,
though the dovetailing constructions are often not available within
less powerful families than Turing machines.

### Introduction

I am writing this as an answer since it partially answers my question
after more thoughts about it, taking existing answers into account. Also, editing my question after three
answers might in this case confuse issues, and I would rather leave
the question as originally written to avoid that.

I first discuss some of my disagreements with the given answers. The
point is not to disparage fair attempts at answering my question (my
thanks for all answers), but to get to the bottom of issues by
discussing or disputing technical points.

I think the original question hardly needs context or motivation. The halting
problem is one of the major questions we ask about automata on the one
hand, and nondeterminism is one very common and useful features of
many automata on the other hand. Furthermore, nondeterminism is not
just a common theoretical device to simplify proofs, but an essential
feature of some families of automata, such as the linear bounded
automaton (LBA), at least at the time of this writing.

Hence it is quite natural to wonder whether the halting problem has
meaning, or a preferred meaning, which and why, in the case of
nondeterministic automata.

### Is the nonderterministic halting problem well addressed?

My question wonders why the halting problem for nondeterministic automata
seems to receive *second class* treatment, which did generate a downvote
and an answer by vzn. The [answer by vzn](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44231/defining-the-halting-problem-for-non-deterministic-automata/44253#44253), which is really more a long
comment, insists that "*nondeterminism seems a very deep/ ubiquitous/
crosscutting concept in CS*", which I never doubted. It also gives one
reference to some reasearch on halting for nondeterministic machines
which is not surprising, but does not really address my point. My
point is that I do not recall actually seeing a definition of the
halting problem aimed at nondeterministic machines, though I did read
some litterature in the field. It is not addressed, AFAIK, in my
reference textbook (Hopcroft+Ullman 1979). It seem often implicit in
the mind of people that they are considering deterministic automata,
usually Turing machines, whose reference definition is deterministic.

For example, in the question [Why is the halting problem decidable for
LBA?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22925/why-is-the-halting-problem-decidable-for-lba), Yuval Filmus forgot in [his answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22925/why-is-the-halting-problem-decidable-for-lba/22926#22926) that LBAs are nondeterministic
devices - but brilliantly saved his answer with [a 4 words comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22925/why-is-the-halting-problem-decidable-for-lba/22926#comment45378_22926).

As a last witness to the fact that this issue is not well addressed in
general (despite some specialized research), I would call the fact
that the issue has to be discussed here.

The [answer from jmite](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44231/defining-the-halting-problem-for-non-deterministic-automata/44236#44236) is the only one that actually attempts to explain
why it might not be well addressed. His first argument is that there are
two possible definitions, but I believe that this situation should
rather encourage more analysis to determine which definition would be
most appropriate. I attempt to do that below.

He also suggests that, since a nondeterministic TM can always be
converted into an equivalent deterministic one, there is not much
point in worrying about the issue of halting in the nondeterministic
case. I am not fully convinced, but it may be perceived as a good
reason by many. However, the argument does not apply to Linear Bounded
Automata (LBA), because it is still an open problem whether
deterministic LBA are equivalent to nondeterministic LBA. And there
are other families of automata for which the deterministic subfamily
is weaker that the whole nondeterministic family (PDA for example).

I also disagree with the last point, asserting that we should not be
concerned with nondeterministic halting because proofs are easier
with deterministic machines. Raphael objected to that in [a comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44231/defining-the-halting-problem-for-nondeterministic-automata/44236#comment89954_44236):
"*I usually find reductions to harder problems easier*". Indeed, for
many types of automata, the nondeterministic version serves mainly to
simplify proofs, such as reduction to that type of automaton. Having
in addition two forms of halting that may be used, as suggested by
jmite himself, could even be considered an advantage as it give more
flexibility to address problems.

### On the definition of the nondeterministic halting problem

<sub>Note: the use of the word "universal" in the following text refers
to [universal quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification), NOT to [universal Turing machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine)</sub>

The [answer from jmite](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44231/defining-the-halting-problem-for-non-deterministic-automata/44236#44236) is the most detailed.

This answer conjectures that nondeterministic automata foster less
effort on the halting problem because it can be defined in two
different ways (the terminology is mine):

- **existential halting**: is there a halting computation
  of automaton $M$ on input $x$?
- **universal halting**: are there only halting computations of automaton $M$ on input $x$?

The only definition I had suggested adequate is *existential halting*.

**Proposition 1**: When a nondeterministic automaton is universally
 halting on input $x$, it can only have a finite number of halting
 computations on that input.

**Proof**:  This is easily proved with [König's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_lemma), since the
number of possible nondeterministic choices at each step is bounded
for a given automaton. If there were infinitely many halting
computations, we could label each configuration with each of the
computational paths leading to it, which would make a computation
graph with infinitely many nodes, but only finite nondeterministic
branching at each node. By König's lemma, this implies the existence
of an infinite computational path, corresponding to a non-halting
computation.

### The case of (nondeterministic) Turing machines

So now, let's examine halting in the case of nondeterministic Turing
machine (NTM).

To analyze the two definitions, the simplest is indeed to consider
deterministic versions of non deterministic machines, which can be
achieved, as [recalled by Hendrik Jan](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44231/defining-the-halting-problem-for-non-deterministic-automata/44236#comment89960_44236), by dovetailing of all possible
computations.

But there are (at least) two ways of dovetailing computations for
determinization, though only one is usually considered:

- **existential dovetailing determinization** which simulates all
  computations in parallel and terminates when one of the simulated
  computations terminates.
- **universal dovetailing determinization** which simulates all
  computations in parallel and terminates only when all of the
  simulated computations terminate. But it can conceivably
  enumerates in some way the terminating computations, or count them.

**Proposition 2**:

- A nondeterministic TM $M$ is existentially halting on input $x$ iff
  its existential dovetailing determinization $M_\exists$ is a TM that
  halts on input $x$.
- A nondeterministic TM $M$ is universally halting on input $x$ iff
  its universal dovetailing determinization $M_\forall$ is a TM that
  halts on input $x$.

**Proof**: The proof for the existential case is obvious. For the
  universal case, the universal dovetailing determinization will halt
  iff it simulates a finite number of computations, all of which are
  halting. Given a nondeterministic TM $M$, if it halts universally on
  input $x$, then, by proposition 1, it has only a finite number of distinct
  computations, which all halt. Hence its universal dovetailing
  determinization $M_\forall$ halts on input $x$. The converse is
  straightforward.

**Theorem 3**: The halting problem for deterministic TM, and the existential
and universal halting problems for nondeterministic TM are Turing
equivalent.

**Proof**: This results from proposition 2 and from the fact that
  deterministic TMs are a subset of nondeterministic TM, where both
  existential and universal halting reduce to simple deterministic
  halting.

Hence, from a computability point of view, and I am tempted to say
from a symbol pushing point of view, it seems that it does not
really matter which definition is chosen, existential or universal,
for the nondeterministic halting problem.

### Why choose one definition of NTM halting, and which

However, is there much sense to a determinization process that does
not preserve the language recognized by the original automaton?

The essence of the use of nondeterminism in language recognition is
that it assumes an oracle that is supposed to guess a right
computational path whenever there is one that will lead to acceptance,
*a fundamentally existential view*.

In a nondeterministic computation, there is no difference between
rejection on halting and non-halting. In both cases, no conclusion can
be drawn. The language recognized is not changed if you replace
rejection on halting by a non-halting infinite loop, which can be done
for all nondeterministic automata I can think of, including NFA (just
add a looping $\epsilon$-transition on the failure states). This is
also true of deterministic automata, provided there is a special
symbol marking the end of the input, as usually done for LBA.

Thus acceptance by halting may be seen as a canonical form of
acceptance for nondeterministic automata.

Considering this canonical view, the **halting problem** may also be expressed
equivalently as the **recognition problem**:

> Is there a uniform procedure that, given a language $L$ recognized
>     by a Turing machine $M$, can decide for any word $x$ whether $x\in L$?

This evidences the close ties between recursive enumerabiliy and the
halting problem. This equivalence between deciding halting of the TM $M$
on input $x$ and containement of $x$ in the language $M$ recognizes is
true for both deterministic TM and for nondeterministic ones,
provided we consider the existential definition of nondeterministic
halting.

However, in the case universal halting, this close relation is lost. A
similar statement can be made, but for a different language than the
one recognized by the NTM (or alternatively for a different,
universal, definition of what is the language recognized by a NTM).

When developing a theory, it is essential to use consistent
definitions so as to emphasize structures and relations in their
simplest and most perspicuous form. It is quite clear that in the
present case, consistency with other definitions suggests that
**existential halting is the natural definition of halting for
nondeterministic Turing machines.**

Of course, one may always be interested in analyzing universal
halting. Similarly, one could also develop a theory of universal
acceptance for NTM based on the requirement that a string $x$ is
accepted iff all computation on input $x$ halt and accept. But,
apparently, it is not considered a major issue in the theory of Turing
machines.

### The case of other families of automata

Parts of the above analysis cannot be extended to most families of
nondeterministic automata. For example a pushdown atomaton (PDA) may
define languages that cannot be recognized by a deterministic PDA.
The same may be true of LBAs. Other parts can be extended to all
nondeterministic families.

Regarding the definition of nondeterministic halting, even though the
reasoning used in the Turing machine case may not be usable, it seems
that the only sensible choice is to adopt a definition which is
consistent with the one used for nondeterministic Turing machines,
hence the existential definition.

The definition of the Halting problem for these families of
nondeterministic automata follows, and conforms the definition
proposed in the question.

Comment: There is a difference between Automata and Turing Machine in terms of Halting terminology, because "halting" is generally applied only to Turing Machines. When discussing the related concept for Automata it is Language Recognition (Accept and Reject) which is used. The two sets of terms converge with a Turing Machine, but here Accept (and Reject) are now merely semi-decidable. So Accept is used in place of Halt. But *only* in a Non-deterministic TM do we have to deal with branches which might *both* Halt, but one gives Accept and the other Reject. This is a possibility not  discussed here.

Comment: @RoySimpson This seems an interesting comment, but I must beg forgiveness as I am taken by another work and cannot afford the time to get all this back in my head just now (I tried, longer than I should have).

Comment: If you want I could write up this as an extended Answer, with definitions and references (e.g. to Hopcroft and Ullman, etc). I agree with your original question that there is a difference in the way that NDTMs are treated in the literature, compared to what one might expect. You can then study the Answer when you have spare time.

Comment: @RoySim Not really my place to decide that for you, especially since I am a bit
out of things right now. People who may have an opinion are the
community of users.  What I mean is that if you consider you have a contribution to the
topic, and time to do it, it might be a good
idea. You are the only judge.
The way this started was an issue about termination of Non-deterministic
LBA. See reference in the question. This contradicts a bit your assertion
that "halting" is generally applied only to Turing Machines. The issue
probably occurs also for other kinds of non-deterministic automata.

Comment: The LBA problem is decidable - hence does not have the "halting problem" that a general TM has. See this paper on LBA https://web.archive.org/web/20070205070159/http://www.cs.uky.edu/~lewis/texts/theory/automata/lb-auto.pdf Also an LBA is equivalent to Context Sensitive Grammar acceptors. Do you have an issue with these results? Because (deterministic and nondeterministic) automata are decidable, of more importance is what languages they accept. The "halting problem" is for entire Turing Machines. *Extending* deterministic TMs to NDTM *does* introduce some new considerations, however.

Comment: @RoySimpso "The LBA halting problem is decidable" : yes. But you have to be able to state
it.  LBAs do have a halting problem ... that happens to have a solution,
unlike Turing Machines. Actually they have two halting problems, since it is
not known whether deterministic and non-deterministic LBA are
equivalent. Halting problem is not a problem (a fault) with TM, but a question
about TM. Are you asserting that TM are the only kind of automata such that
halting is undecidable? I am not even sure this sentence has meaning without first coming to a consensus on what is a family of automata.

Comment: I think that one way the Question and your Answer could be made clearer is if there was a recognition that there are *four* a priori distinct types of machine model under discussion: (1) Non-Deterministic TM; (2) Deterministic TM; (3) Non-deterministic LBA; (4) Deterministic LBA. These machine types have to be proven equivalent or otherwise. Theorems 9.6, 9.7, 9.8 in Hopcroft and Ullman cover much of your questions about LBA. (e.g. (3) is decidable). The *unanswered* question about LBA is whether (3) = (4). The Answers above discuss (1) vs (2) and not LBA issues. We also have  (2) >(3) >= (4).

Comment: @RoySimpson I know only 3 numbers: 0, 1 and many. TM and LBA is more than 1, thus is many. Why exclude other automata one could imagine, that have a ND variant. I was not, NOT, trying to solve a problem with LBA, or even with TM. I was trying to understand what it means to question the halting properties of some kind of ND automata family. I wanted to know how halting is to be defined, and why so, in the context of non-determinism. The various answers and the discussions show that there was matter for debate and clarification, and I did learn from them. TM was only a convenient example.