Power of Nondeterministic Machines
I am trying to understand the concept of nondeterminism in the context of computational complexity, particularly with reference to problems like PATH, which is in the class NL. I have read that PATH is in NL because we can "nondeterministically select the nodes of a path connecting $s$ to $t$." However, I am unclear on what exactly "nondeterministically" means in this context.
Specifically:

Does "nondeterministically" imply that the machine effectively explores all possible choices simultaneously, as if performing a form of parallel computation?
Why is PATH not in $L$ (deterministic logarithmic space)? Is it because deterministic machines must keep track of visited nodes and systematically brute-force through all possible paths, which could require more than logarithmic space?
How should I conceptualise the difference between how deterministic and nondeterministic machines approach problems like PATH in terms of time and space?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

We prefer that you ask only one question per post.  Regarding nondeterminism, I suggest reading https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/80923/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/5008/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/88403/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/80563/755,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_Turing_machine,
