# What is difference between Hidden Markov Model and Non-deterministic Finite-State Machine?

Tags: finite-automata, hidden-markov-models

As the question implies, can you mention any difference between Hidden Markov Model and Non-deterministic Finite-State Machine? Are they different or the same?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/5008/755

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deterministic Finite State Machines have at most one trace for a given input. Nondeterministic Finite State Machines may have many traces for a given input. A Hidden Markov Model in some sense fits "in between" these extremes as the traces are probabilistic. With a Hidden Markov Model we do not have complete freedom to choose which trace to follow as we are governed by probabilities. A Hidden Markov Model is essentially a transducer-style Finite State Machine having outputs & transitions governed by a random process; the outputs generated at states are per a random variable model of what happens at that state, e.g., "if the weather is cloudy then 20% it will turn rainy / 80% it will turn sunny".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Now one question has arisen about the difference between Probabilistic Finite-State Machines and HMM!!
Can you clarify this one?

Comment: HMM is in other words a special type of Probabilistic FSM.